# Remover borda do HTML ou body

Tags: html, css, css-border

Preciso remover essas borda (que destaquei em verde) que ficam na minha extensão. Quero que não tenha nada ali ou pelo menos que seja transparente para que o `box-shadow` tenha efeito e fique redondo assim como a `div`.

Já tentei definir o `background-color` do `body` para `transparent` mas não funciona. Também tentei arredondar o `body` junto com a `div` para ver se corrigia mas também não funcionou.

Segue imagem demonstrando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o meu código:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #48ff00;
    margin: 0%;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
}

#corpo {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #592C90;
  box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 10%) 0 2px 4px 0;
  border: 2px #000000 solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
}


/* ------ Botões ------ */


.toggle {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.toggle > input {
    display: none;
}

.toggle > label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 52px;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    border: 2px #8E8F93 solid;
    border-radius: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.toggle > label:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    display: block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    content: '';
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.toggle > label:active:after {
    transform: scale(1.15, 0.85);
}
.toggle > input:checked ~ label {
    background-color: #4cda64;
    border-color: #8E8F93;
}
.toggle > input:checked ~ label:after {
    left: 25px;
}
.toggle > input:disabled ~ label {
    background-color: #d5d5d5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.toggle > input:disabled ~ label:after {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="corpo">
            <div class="toggle">
                <input type="checkbox" id="onoff">
                <label for="onoff"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="toggle">
                <input type="checkbox" id="onoff2">
                <label for="onoff2"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: não pode só remover o `background-color` do body?

Comment: @RicardoPontual se fizer isso ele fica branco

Answer (score 0):

Antes:

```
body {
    background-color: #48ff00;
    margin: 0%;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Depois:

```
body {
    background-color: none;
    margin: 0%;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
}
```

Código completo:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: none;
    margin: 0%;
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
}

#corpo {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #592C90;
  box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 10%) 0 2px 4px 0;
  border: 2px #000000 solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
}


/* ------ Botões ------ */


.toggle {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.toggle > input {
    display: none;
}

.toggle > label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    width: 52px;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    border: 2px #8E8F93 solid;
    border-radius: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.toggle > label:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    display: block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    content: '';
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.toggle > label:active:after {
    transform: scale(1.15, 0.85);
}
.toggle > input:checked ~ label {
    background-color: #4cda64;
    border-color: #8E8F93;
}
.toggle > input:checked ~ label:after {
    left: 25px;
}
.toggle > input:disabled ~ label {
    background-color: #d5d5d5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.toggle > input:disabled ~ label:after {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="corpo">
            <div class="toggle">
                <input type="checkbox" id="onoff">
                <label for="onoff"></label>
            </div>

            <div class="toggle">
                <input type="checkbox" id="onoff2">
                <label for="onoff2"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Espero ser isso e espero ter ajudado

Comment: Pode utilizar transparent ao inves de none tmb.

Comment: Continuo tendo um fundo branco mesmo com ```background-color: none;``` ou ```background-color: transparent;```. Segue imagem: https://imgur.com/a/ayg81L9

Comment: Vou tentar uma coisa, se funcionar retorno o script.

Comment: beleza. Valeu mano!